# JavaScript If An Array Value Equals An Object

Tags: javascript

The values for "A" & "B" equal "Value" however the value for "C" equals `[object Object]`:

```
{
    "A": "Value",
    "B": "Value",
    "C": {
        "I": "Value",
        "II": "Value"
    }
}
```

I have a loop and would like to add an `IF` to check whether the `value` is equal to an `[object Object]`, ie; has more than one field within.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *I have a loop* - show that loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just transform each value into a `string` with `.toString()` function and check the result. If given value is an object - nested, single or even empty - it will return `"[object Object]"`.

**Note**: It will work even if a given value is `string`, `number`, `boolean` or `array`.

```js
var obj = {
    "A": "Value",
    "B": true,
    "C": {
        "I": "Value",
        "II": "Value",
        "III": {foo: 'bar'},
        "IV": {},
        "V": 'foo'
    },
    "D": 24,
    "E": ['hi']
};

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj[key].toString() != "[object Object]" ) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  } else {
    console.log("It's an object");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to use typeof x where x is whatever you are checking. For "A" and "B" it would be "string" and for "C" it would be "object".

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

It describes the typeof operator.

```
if(typeof obj === 'object')
{
    ...
}
else if(typeof obj === 'string')
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let test = {
      "first": "fetr",
      "second": {
        "edwr":12,
        "ewrgtr":32
      }
    };

    Object.keys(test).forEach(function (key) {
      if(typeof test[key] === 'object'){
        console.log(key,test[key]);
      }
    });
```

This works as of ECMAscript 5 :)